# MYSQL Workbench - Query for left join

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm try to get the output of How many times each location is used for clus meetings, trainings, and competitions for my database. I figured out how to do each separately but am having trouble combining them into one output table.

```
SELECT l.LocId, l.Postcode, count(c.CId) FROM locations l left join competitions c
on l.LocId = c.LocId
GROUP BY LocId;

SELECT l.LocId, l.Postcode, count(t.TId) FROM locations l left join trainings t
on l.LocId = t.LocId
GROUP BY LocId;

SELECT l.LocId, l.Postcode, count(cl.Cno) FROM locations l left join clubs cl
on l.LocId = cl.LocId
GROUP BY LocId;
```

I've tried combining them using left join and can't find an other ways to try

Comment: Are you looking for UNION (3 rows) or do you want all 3 counts to be on a single line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use subqueries in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT 
  l.LocId,
  l.Postcode,
  (SELECT count(c.CId) FROM competitions c WHERE c.LocId = l.LocId) as CId_count,
  (SELECT count(t.TId) FROM trainings t WHERE t.LocId = l.LocId) as TId_count,
  (SELECT count(cl.Cno) FROM clubs cl WHERE cl.LocId = l.LocId) as Vno_count
FROM locations l
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `LocId`, `CId`, `TId` and `Cno` are the primary keys of the tables, do a `LEFT` join of `locations` to all 3 tables and aggregate with `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`:

```
SELECT l.LocId, l.Postcode, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT c.CId) AS competitions_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT t.TId) AS trainings_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT cl.Cno) AS clubs_count
FROM locations l 
LEFT JOIN competitions c ON l.LocId = c.LocId
LEFT JOIN trainings t ON l.LocId = t.LocId
LEFT JOIN clubs cl ON l.LocId = cl.LocId
GROUP BY l.LocId;
```